# How to force a symlink creation by overriding the existing symlink?

Tags: node.js, symlink

I use the `fs` module to create symlinks.

```
fs.symlink("target", "path/to/symlink", function (e) {
   if (e) { ... }
});
```

If the `path/to/symlink` already exists, an error is sent in the callback.

How can I force symlink creation and override the existing symlink?

Is there another alternative than `check error + delete existing symlink + try again`?

Comment: There may be modules that will provide such functionality, but in the end it will also use the method you describe (that, or _"check existence + delete if exists + symlink"_).

Comment: I don't how to do this in js, but in linux you can override symlink, so you can call a shell script from node. Source: http://serverfault.com/questions/389997/how-to-override-update-a-symlink

Comment: @robertklep Well, for sure. I can create a module as well, just for this thing, but I'd be interested if there is a native way.

Comment: @vanadium23 I know I can use `ln -f` but, I don't want to. I want to use the file system api.

Comment: @IonicăBizău if by "native" you mean "using `fs`", then the answer is no :-)

Comment: @robertklep OK, so I built a module to do this thing. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When using the `ln` command line tool we can do this using the `-f` (force) flag

```
ln -sf target symlink-name
```

However, this is not possible using the `fs` API unless we implement this feature in a module.

I created [`lnf`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-lnf) - a module to override existing symlinks.

```
// Dependencies
var Lnf = require("lnf");

// Create the symlink
Lnf.sync("foo", __dirname + "/baz");

// Override it
Lnf("bar", __dirname + "/baz", function (err) {
    console.log(err || "Overriden the baz symlink.");
});
```

[Read the full documentation on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-lnf/)

Comment: WARNING: the method currently used in the `lnf` module does an unlink followed by a symlink. That isn't concurrency safe and leaves a race condition where some other process may create a file between the unlink and the symlink (among other issues). There is a ticket noting this: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-lnf/issues/14

Answer (score 13):

You can create temporary symlink with different (unique) name and then rename it.

Use `fs.symlinkSync(path, tempName)` and then `fs.rename(tempName, name)`.

It may be better than deleting the file when other application depends on its existence (and may accidentaly access it when it is deleted, but not yet recreated).

Comment: As I didn't know that's how POSIX rename() was specified.+1